# How can I make a window active without having to click in it in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, mouse

I have both Windows applications (ie. Ultra Edit text editor) and Linux applications running through Xming and Putty in an xterm window. In previous versions of Windows, I could activate a window by hovering over it. In Windows 10, I need to select the window to make it active. Is there a setting in Windows 10 to allow the window the mouse is in/over to be active without selecting it?

Comment: [How do you enable focus follows mouse in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/q/954021/241386), [How can I activate the window my mouse is currently hovering over?](https://superuser.com/q/19639/241386), [Hovering over window switches focus to it on Windows 8.1](https://superuser.com/q/900866/241386), [Is there a way to automatically move focus to whatever monitor the mouse cursor is on?](https://superuser.com/q/858606/241386)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you enable focus follows mouse in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/954021/how-do-you-enable-focus-follows-mouse-in-windows-10)

Answer (score 6):

To activate a Window with mouse hovering, you go to the Control Center.

```
Control-Center -> Ease of access -> Make the mouse easier to use -> Activate a window by hovering over it with the mouse
```